# Return Distinct row while exluding one column from the distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, union

I have the following query...

```
SELECT           
      DEP.CUST_ORG_CD,
      DEP.CUST_NO,
      DEP.DP_ACT_NO
FROM R_DBLNK_US.DW_TRN_DEPO_ACC_D DEP

UNION

SELECT
      DEP.CUST_ORG_CD,
      DEP.CUST_NO,
      DEP.DP_ACT_NO
FROM R_DBLNK_US.DW_MST_ACC_D DEP
```

...that returns two rows (one each from each table) of

```
CUST_ORG_CD    CUST_NO    ACT_NO
5              321        8
5              321        9
```

which I store in a temporary table. I then want to return all three columns, but with DISTINCT on the first two, such that in this case the second row would not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `not exists` in the second subquery, to filter out records that match the first resultset on the first two columns.

```
select cust_org_cd, cust_no,dp_act_no
from r_dblnk_us.dw_trn_depo_acc_d
union all
select cust_org_cd, cust_no, dp_act_no
from r_dblnk_us.dw_mst_acc_d d2
where not exists (
    select 1
    from r_dblnk_us.dw_trn_depo_acc_d d1
    where d1.cust_org_cd = d2.cust_org_cd and d1.cust_no = d2.cust_no
)
```

Side note: I changed `union` to `union all`; unless the subqueries themselves generate duplicates, this does not change the resultset, and is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest the use of something like the following to define the one you want to keep and then filter by WHERE RowNumber = 1

```
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ORG_CD, CUST_NO ORDER BY ACT_NO) AS RowNumber
```